# SwiftUI navigate to bottom of NavigationView stack

Tags: swiftui, reset, navigationview

I have the following set up where a parent view holds a `NavigationView` which displays a series of pages, A, B and C. On page C there is a button which hides the navigation view. I want to have it so that when the navigation view is shown again, it automatically navigates to page A, however I am unsure how to do this with SwiftUI, how can this be achieved?

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var showNavigation:Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showNavigation = true
            }) {
                Text("Show navigation")
            }
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: ChildA(showNavigation: $showNavigation)) {
                    Text("Go to A")
                }
            }.opacity(showNavigation ? 1.0 : 0.0)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildA: View {
    @Binding var showNavigation:Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("A")
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildB(showNavigation: $showNavigation)) {
                           Text("Go to B")
                       }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildB: View {
    @Binding var showNavigation:Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("B")
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildC(showNavigation: $showNavigation)) {
                           Text("Go to C")
                       }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildC: View {
    @Binding var showNavigation:Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("C")
            Button(action: {
                self.showNavigation = false
            }) {
                Text("Hide Navigation")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Flow]

Comment: you can add `isActive` to `NavigationLink` to get more control over the navigation stack. For more details go to https://dev.to/gualtierofr/navigation-in-swiftui-1hg2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting here is not complicated. One thing is for any intermediate view, you have to set `.isDetailLink(false)`. Otherwise, they will be kept during rewinding.

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var showNavigation:Bool = true
    @State var isActive:Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showNavigation = true
            }) {
            Text("Show navigation")
        }
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink.init(
                destination: ChildA(showNavigation: $showNavigation, isActive: $isActive), 
                isActive: $isActive) {
                    Text("Go to A")
                }
            }.opacity(showNavigation ? 1.0 : 0.0)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildA: View {
    @Binding var showNavigation:Bool
    @Binding var isActive:Bool
    @State var isNextActive:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("A")
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ChildB(showNavigation: $showNavigation, isActive: $isNextActive), 
                isActive: $isNextActive) {
                     Text("Go to B")
                }.isDetailLink(false)
            }.onReceive(Just(isNextActive)) { isNextActive in
                if isNextActive == false && (!self.showNavigation) {

                    self.isActive = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildB: View {
    @Binding var showNavigation:Bool
    @Binding var isActive:Bool
    @State var isNextActive:Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("B")
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildC(showNavigation: $showNavigation, isActive: $isNextActive), isActive: $isNextActive) {
                Text("Go to C")
            }.isDetailLink(false)
        }.onReceive(Just(isNextActive)) { isNextActive in
            if isNextActive == false && (!self.showNavigation) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.isActive = false
                }
            }
        }             
    }
}

struct ChildC: View {
    @Binding var showNavigation:Bool
    @Binding var isActive:Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("C")
            Button(action: {
                self.showNavigation = false
                self.isActive = false
            }) {
                Text("Hide Navigation")
            }
        }
    }
}
```